# CSS Grids and Fraction Unit

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand the basics of CSS grids but have a problem with fraction `grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);` unit.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'sidebar content content' 'sidebar content content' 'footer footer footer';
}

.item-1 {
  grid-area: content;
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: #852021;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-area: header;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nulla sapiente cumque ratione quas consequatur, quaerat qui possimus et voluptatibus expedita tempore porro fuga aliquam, cum aut rerum perspiciatis blanditiis.
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nulla sapiente cumque ratione quas consequatur, quaerat qui possimus et voluptatibus expedita tempore porro fuga aliquam, cum aut rerum perspiciatis blanditiis.
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nulla sapiente cumque ratione quas consequatur, quaerat qui possimus et voluptatibus expedita tempore porro fuga aliquam, cum aut rerum perspiciatis blanditiis.
  </div>
  <div class="item-4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nulla sapiente cumque ratione quas consequatur, quaerat qui possimus et voluptatibus expedita tempore porro fuga aliquam, cum aut rerum perspiciatis blanditiis.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to define a ratio.  So if you use "1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr" this means 4 columns, each with 1 share of the width, so they will each be 25% of the width.  If however you use "1fr 2fr 1fr" then there will be 3 columns, where the first and last will both be 25% but the middle one will be 50%.

It makes adding another column easier, without having to do the maths to work out what all the percentages should be now.

See [this article](https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Rik Lewis ! Could you explain  this `grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr)` for above code snippet ?

Comment: Yeah, `repeat(4, 1fr)` is the shorthand for `repeat(1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr)`, and the `/` is indicating that before it is `grid-template-rows` and after is `grid-template-columns`.  See here for more information... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Answer (score 0):

The first part defines 4 rows, each with 1 fr, so each row will get 25% of the total height

The second part defines 3 columns, each with 1 fr, so each column will get 33% of the total width.

THis agrees with the following definition of areas, where there are 4 strings, one for each row, with 3 names in every string, one for each column.